# Cannot pass data ajax in ci

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

```
$("body").on('click', '.name', function(e) {
   //var valueofbutton = $(this).val();         
            $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "response",
     data: "name=John&location=Boston",
     success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     }
});

});
```

my response controller

```
Class Response extends CI_Controller{


public function index()
{

$data=$this->input->post('name'); 

echo $data;

}


}
```

it shows me some errors i dont know what kind of error is it !

my alert gives this information

```
Data Saved: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unterminated comment starting line 25 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\vacationgod\application\controllers\response.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
John
```

and i cant see any print information like `john` which i pass to response controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your ajax code.Controller is ok.

```
$("body").on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?=base_url("controller_name/function_name") ?>',
    data: {name: "John",location:"Boston"},
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + response);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` should be an object and remove `.name`. change that line in you ajax like this:

```
$("body").on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "response.php",
    data: {name: "John",location:"Boston"},
    success: function(msg) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
  });
});
```